# What happens during a file upload?

Tags: php

I upload a file to my server (Server A) using a PHP script. With this same PHP script I again upload using CURL from my site to another server (Server B) using what was just uploaded like this:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

My question is this: Does this script wait for the file to be completely uploaded to Server A before continuing to upload to Server B?

If not, how do I get the script to wait for everything to upload to me then continue to upload to Server B without the script ending its execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your PHP script isn't run until the file is completely uploaded and available in `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`