# How to reject file upload before php saves it?

Tags: php, file-upload

As i understand PHP saves file to temporary directory and after that i can work with the file through $_FILES.

I need to check fe things BEFORE PHP starts downloading the file - if the session is valid, if referrer is valid... so i can prevent saving rubbish to the php temporary directory by unauthorised uploaders.

it is any way how to do that?

i know how to do that nicely in perl but i'm looking for pure php solution without php.ini modifications or .htaccess modifications.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/handle-file-uploads-php/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the Content-Type to something that PHP can't parse (for example 'raw/data') you can read all the POST data from `php://input`, so when the script run you can do the validation first and if you happy then read the data and save them to disk.

here is PHP code

```
<?php 
    preg_match("/^(.*)\/([^\/]+)$/", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], $SRVR);
    $SRVR=$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'].$SRVR[1];
    if (!strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $SRVR)) {
        echo "Status: 418 I'm a teapot (RFC 2324)\n\n";
        exit;
    }

    session_name('MYSESSION');
    session_start();

    if (!$_SESSION['LoggedID']) {
        echo "Invalid Session";
        exit;
    }

    session_write_close(); // quite useful - 'unlock' the session variables

    $HEADERS=getallheaders();

    if (!$HEADERS['UPL_FileName']) {
        echo "Invalid FileName";
        exit;
    }
    if (!$HEADERS['UPL_TMP']) {
        $HEADERS['UPL_TMP']=rtrim(base64_encode(md5(microtime())),"=");
    }

    $in=fopen('php://input', 'r');
    $SIZE=0;
    $out=fopen('tmp/'.$HEADERS['UPL_TMP'], 'wb');
    while(!feof($in)){
        usleep(10000); // simulate slow upload - for testing progress status/bar
        fwrite($out, fgets($in, 2048));
    }

    fclose($out);
    fclose($in);

    rename('tmp/'.$HEADERS['UPL_TMP'], $HEADERS['UPL_FileName']);   

    echo "Upload OK [", $HEADERS['UPL_TMP'], "]";

?>
```

and the JavaScript code as well

```
function getXMLHttp() {
    var ajax;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        ajax=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
    return ajax;
}

var ajax=getXMLHttp();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState==4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
}
ajax.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'raw/data');
ajax.setRequestHeader('UPL_FileName', 'tmp/test.jpg');
ajax.setRequestHeader('UPL_TMP', 'ABCDE');
ajax.send(document.getElementById('uploader').files[0]);
```

...expecting the file tag with id='uploader'

hope it will help somebody ;-)

Comment: Clever! Definitely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: in normal form posted operation, no.  PHP cannot "ask for more".  Files uploaded through a form via PUT or POST as `multipart/form-data` leave the client, come to your web server, and get handed entirely over to PHP for processing into `$_FILES`.

Obviosusly this is ripe for a denial of service attack, among [a host of other vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload).

Javascript, specifically using [the HTML5 File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) lets you gain access to file data in the browser.  You can then send any part of said file data back to your PHP for validation (using XHR), then proceed to upload if such validation passes.

Comment: as i've expected ;-( so old good perl will need to sort that out for me

Comment: Yep.  But, I'm curious... how Perl would "ask for more"?  I presume it's perl via CGI, which would still be subject to the mechanism of HTTP, which sends all the file data over the wire.

Comment: With Perl it's easy ;-) because the script is run BEFORE the 'upload begins' and you have to fetch the file manually. So first i can check few ENV variables, do some checkup and if its everything ok i'll start to read STDIN - data waiting for me to fetch - the file. If i'm not happy i can exit the script which will physically stops the upload so no unwanted data will be uploaded. I think you can do this with PHP somehow just content type needs to be changed to prevent PHP to start upload (probably)

Comment: I dug thru CGI.pm and by jingo, yep. I had *completely* forgotten about that, having not used Perl on the web for a long time.  But that is really easy, really nice, and really quite cool.  Should be  in PHP!  Thanks for replying with details.  You might also find [this link helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463964/any-documentation-about-how-apache-handles-file-uploads)

Comment: You don't need to use CGI.pm - i'm not using libraries for very small things like upload is ;-) ...i've just copy-paste the main part of my uploader which will give you idea how perl uploader works [http://ideone.com/kmJIUN](http://ideone.com/kmJIUN) the code is not fantastic and my not work - its copied part of my (long-years) working uploader and there are few things added just for testing/tunning

Comment: Understood, I was using CGI.pm as a reference of how a perl implementation could do it, not as the only way.